# HTTP GET Server - Incorrect Header

Tags: c#, header

I am coding a HTTP Server, but when I create the header and send it.

It returns: `The connection to 127.0.0.1 was interrupted.`

My code to make the header is:

```
        string header = "\r\n";
        header += "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
        header += "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";
        header += "\r\n";
        header += "<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body>Testing</body></html>";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're *starting* with a line break - you shouldn't. Basically, change this:

```
string header = "\r\n";
header += "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
```

to

```
string header = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
```

Comment: Tried that still returned "The connection to 127.0.0.1 was interrupted."

Comment: @54.224.239.54: Now would be a good time to post a short but complete program then, and also tell us what you're using to test it. (A browser? Something else?)

Comment: I'm using a browser, there isn't really else much to show. It accepts the socket and sends data then closes it.

Comment: Turns out the problem was I was closing the socket after sending but I'm not sure why that was causing the problem, any ideas?

Comment: @54.224.239.54: Not without seeing a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, no. I suggest you try to come up with one, and put it in a new question.